# Развернуть вектор, начиная с минимального элемента

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Есть вектор `vect`, состоящий из `N`  элементов, и нужно развернуть вектор(записать в обратном порядке) начиная с минимального элемента вектора.

```
vector<int>::iterator  min = vect.begin();
int k = 0;
for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (vect[i] < *min)
    {
        *min = vect[i];
        k = i;
    }
}
```

Нашел номер минимального элемента: `k` и сам минимальный элемент: `min`. Дальше пытаюсь через итератор `min` поменять местами элементы:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (N - k)/2; i++)
{
    int chng;
    chng = *(min + i);
    *(min + i) = *(vect.end()-1 - i);
    *(vect.end()-1 - i) = chng;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь инструментами стандартной библиотеки из заголовка `<algorithm>`:

1. Найти минимальный элемент: [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element)
2. Развернуть последовательность: [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

---

```
std::reverse(std::min_element(vect.begin(), vect.end()), vect.end());
```

---

Пример программы ([online](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a0b19b10c48ea38)):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print_vector(const std::vector<int> & input)
{
    for (const auto i : input)
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void reverse_vector(std::vector<int> & input)
{
    if (input.empty())
    {
        std::cerr << "vector is empty" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    
    std::reverse(std::min_element(input.begin(), input.end()), input.end());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vect {10, 500, 40, 18, 4, 46, 39, 134, 98};
    
    print_vector(vect);
    
    reverse_vector(vect);
    
    print_vector(vect); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в пои поиске `min`.Менял содержимое указателя, вместо того, чтобы изменить расположение.
В итоге:

```
vector<int>::iterator  min = vect.begin();
int k = 0;
for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (vect[i] < *min)
    {
        min = vect.begin()+ i;//изменили расположение минимального элемента
        k = i;
    }
}
cout << "min=" << *min << "\n";
for (int i = 0; i <= (N - k)/2; i++)
{
    int chng;
    chng = *(min + i);
    *(min + i) = *(vect.end()-1 - i);
    *(vect.end()-1 - i) = chng;
}
```